# Extracting data for a tag cloud using Lazy.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, node.js, json, null

I've just started using Lazy.js, which is my first exposure to a "functional style" javascript library. I'm still utterly lost as to which of the hundred different functional javascript libraries to use, but so far I like Lazy.js, so I've used it to write a tag harvesting module for a blog engine project I'm working on. For anyone unfamiliar with Lazy.js (even moreso than I am) I'm under the impression its syntax is very similar to Underscore and Lodash.

```
getTagsWithCount: function(articles) {

  var tags = Lazy(articles).compact().pluck("attributes").pluck("tags").flatten().compact().sort().countBy()
  return tags // returns a Lazy.js Sequence
},

// Formats a Sequence of tag objects into the specific kind of JSON array for spoonfeeding to fussy baby tag-cloud.js
formatForTagCloud: function(tags) {
  var keysToJSON = tags.keys().map(function(x){return {"tagName": x, "count": tags.get(x)};}).toArray();
  var json = JSON.stringify(keysToJSON);
  return json;
}
```

#### Specific things I'm interested in/suspect I've done wrong:

- Is there a better way to dodge potential nulls in both the article array and in the tags of each articles than the double `compact()`? What's the performance impact of `compact()`? If it's light, should I make a habit of using it everywhere as a general way of avoiding null/undefined values in arrays?
- Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do in formatForTagCloud? This function was purely to force my data into a format needed by a module I've actually ended up abandoning, but I'm presenting it here because writing it was a bit of a headache. Is there a different/better way of accessing both the key and the value of an ObjectLikeSequence? More to the point, I thought this would be a case where I could use either `merge()` or `zip()`, but neither of those worked, leaving me with this approach which I'm concerned would be considered a bit crude.
- I'm in the habit of creating variables then returning them, but I've seen other people write it the function so that the value is just returned without a variable being created first. Which is better? Are there performance benefits to be gained by doing the latter?
- Should I be putting newlines after some/all of my chained methods? Again, it's something I see, but I also sometimes find it a tiny bit confusing – but that's probably because I'm fairly new to the pattern.

Comment: I'm a little sad there's no tag for Lazy.js yet... does that mean that it's not widely used and learning it instead of one of the other libraries is a bad move on my part? I know the creator of the library hangs out on SO, and I was secretly hoping I could tag Lazy.js and maybe attract his attention for a "review from the master" – if anyone has the rep to add the tag, and feels that Lazy.js is worthy of one, please feel free to add it.

Comment: @Jamal Gotcha, sorry, I was typing this up over morning coffee and maybe feeling a little too flippant about my own work, trying to downplay it a bit, hah.

Comment: It says "This library is experimental and still a work in progress". We'll create the tag when the library stabilizes and gains traction.